# dynamically get jquery object's value

Tags: jquery, object

I have jquery object `myObject` like this(result of console.log())

> Object { Product1 {...}, Product2 {...}, Product3 {...} }

and each of these products' pattern is like this `Object { id="1", name="somename" }`

I want to get the value of the name, when I change the radio button, e.g. if the first radio is checked I should get value of `myObject.Product1`, if second -  `myObject.Product2`. When I e.g. try this `console.log(myObject.Product1)`, it normally outputs `Object { id="1", name="somename" }`, but when I want to do it dynamically like

```
var number = getRadioValue(); // for example returns 1 
var productName = 'Product'+number;
```

then it outputs `myObject.productName` as undefined.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are passing in a variable.. you should use the `object[property]` syntax instead of the `.` notation

```
myObject[productName]
```